# How to get the input text field to change colour using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used this for changing other aspects of the style, but for some reason it won't change the input field colour....
Is it possible to change it this way something like style.background-color: "red";  ? 
Other questions seem to make the space where my error message is, highlighted, rather than the actual text box its self.

JS

```
if (document.getElementById("telno").value == /^\d+$/ ) {
            document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.visibility = "visible";
```

This is the CSS at the moment

```
.error{
display: none;
color: #FF2121;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

h1{
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
color: #0A032F;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
}

h2{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: arial;
color: #33257B;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
}

p{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
}

fieldset{
margin-left: 400px;
margin-right: 400px;
margin-top: 40px;   
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f2f2f2);
}    


label{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
display: inline;
}

.formfield{
margin-left: 25px;
display: inline;
}

#title{
margin-left: 25px;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This seems to blank out the error next to it, not the actual input field text box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

Try this,

`document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.backgroundColor ='red';`

Hope this helps!